# Bootstrap navbar dropdown menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, web, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

```
  <head>
    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.discoverhongkong.com/tc/index.html">快樂香港旅遊</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar1">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/zh_HK.html">機票</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://zh.hotels.com/">訂房</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://www.discoverhongkong.com/tc/plan/guided-tour.html?" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">團體</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.discoverhongkong.com/tc/explore/attractions.html">國內旅遊</li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.discoverhongkong.com/tc/greater-bay-area.html">國外旅遊</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="輸入景點">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Even though I had added the corresponding links and scripts from the Bootstrap documentation in my html, the navbar dropdown menu does not show the dropdown items after I clicked it. May I ask anything that I missed in order to have the dropdown menu function properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove one script you have two time call `bootstrap` js

Remove this
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

Also not needed  `proper.js`

Refer this - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/#js

```html
<head>
    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.discoverhongkong.com/tc/index.html">快樂香港旅遊</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar1">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/zh_HK.html">機票</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://zh.hotels.com/">訂房</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://www.discoverhongkong.com/tc/plan/guided-tour.html?" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">團體</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.discoverhongkong.com/tc/explore/attractions.html">國內旅遊</li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.discoverhongkong.com/tc/greater-bay-area.html">國外旅遊</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="輸入景點">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```